# Can a SQL Server 2008 database support both a REST and SOAP web services within two different endpoints?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, sql-server-2008-r2

Say you have a SQL Server 2008 database.  You build a SOAP web service.  You then deploy or publish this using Visual Studio 2010 in one website.  Now, using the same database, you build a REST web service, in a different solution.  You deploy this on another website.

Can you consume the endpoints and/or .svc file of both the SOAP and REST web services, though they reference the same SQL Server 2008 database?

I don't see why not, but before I go down this path and spend days I'd like to make sure.

Also if there's a performance hit to the database if it is running both SOAP and REST at the same time--again, I don't see why it would matter, but I must make sure.  Thanks.

Comment: What led you to believe that the database either knows or cares about your web service?

Comment: Sure - provided your SQL Server machine has enough horsepower (and RAM!), you can support thousands of concurrent clients - no matter how they connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server won't know anything of your web service - it will just receive queries and return the data to the calling connection (your server-side code in this case).

It doesn't care whether the query originated in VBA, Mgmt Studio, your SOAP service or all three.

Answer (score 2):

The database is completely oblivious of how your clients submit requests.  All it sees is ODBC (or whatever) connections running queries.  You could have 20 people sitting in SQL Developer typing these queries manually, it wouldn't know any better.
So yes, you are right, your question makes no sense -- you can have as many different interfaces as you want, performance/load will be determined *only* by the queries executed.

Comment: OK thought so but you never know so I had to ask.  Thank you.